# Solaris 10 Get latest Installed patches

Tags: solaris, patch-management

I'm trying to find out a way to display the LATEST patches installed in a Solaris box. I know the existence of the commands:

```
showrev - p
patchadd -p
```

But I'd like to see a list of patches sorted by install date just to confirm that the box has the latest patch installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Patches are packages, packages live in in a directory tree for each package which is
here:

```
/var/sadm/pkg
```

The patches are in

```
/var/sadm/patch
```

ls -lrt for each one shows the order they were created on the system.  Patches are NOT necessarily applied in chronological order.  This gives you a rough idea, though.

Did you try the smpatch utility to see if there are pending required patches?

```
smpatch analyze
```

shows what smpatch thinks you are missing.

Reply to sockets issue:
java 1.6.0.10 has issues that cause this for smpatch
Bug ID: 2173292  Bug ID: 6771432  See bugs.sun.com or sun.com

Comment: I think that's a good idea, at least that does give me a list of installed patches sorted by installed date. The smpatch analyze throws the following error: 
Failure: Cannot connect to retrieve detectors.jar: Unconnected sockets not implemented

Comment: See socket issues above, added to answer

Answer (score 1):

Check PCA [Patch Check Advanced](http://www.par.univie.ac.at/solaris/pca/)

It's a perl script. You will need an Oracle account and access to internet.

If you want to know if a patch is installed, obsoleted or there is an update with "pca  " will show it

> PCA is a perl script which generates lists of installed and missing patches for Oracle Solaris systems and optionally downloads and installs patches. By default, if run without any option or operand, PCA shows a list of all patches which are not installed in their most recent revision.

```
Here's some sample output from pca -l all, which shows a list of all installed and missing patches:

  Using /var/tmp/patchdiag.xref from Feb/29/04
  Host: myhost (SunOS 5.9/Generic_117171-09/sparc/sun4u)
  List: all (7/2182)
  Patch  IR   CR RSB Age Synopsis
  ------ -- - -- --- --- --------------------------------------------------
  112785 42 < 43 RS-  18 X11 6.6.1: Xsun patch
  112787 01 = 01 --- 999 X11 6.6.1: twm patch
  112807 10 = 10 RS-   9 CDE 1.5: dtlogin patch
```